# Detecting When a Struct or Hashtable Get Modified or Corrupted

Tags: runtime-error, runtime, common-lisp, hashtable

Are there any tools in Common Lisp that can be used to debug a condition along the following lines?

There is a hashtable that gets modified (one of key's values turns to NIL), and I am trying to debug it. I was able to narrow it down to where it is supposedly happening, but the table does not explicitly get modified there via the official accessors.

I can't post code because it is proprietary.

Comment: What is the implementation? Are there any threading issues?

Comment: What do you mean by “one of key's values”? Is a value modified or a key?

Comment: a key has only one value in a hash-table, it doesn't have multiple values.

Comment: It is an Allegro. And, yes, I meant that a particular key has a value that gets modified.

Comment: if it's allegro you should ask support

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest two things. The first is to try to trace the function that modifies hash tables. That is `(setf gethash)` except that `gethash` is an *accessor* and not a *function*. To find out which function is used by the implementation to update the hash-table, do e.g.

```
(disassemble (compile (defun foo (x y) (setf (gethash x y) t))))
```

which shows assembly code that should contain a call to an internal function with a name like `puthash`.

The act of `(trace puthash)` might lead to a problem as the implementation might update a hash-table as part of this call. But assuming it works, it might show you where an unexpected hash-table update takes place.

Some implementations have extended the functionality of `trace`. For example Allegro CL offer [many trace options](https://franz.com/support/documentation/10.1/doc/debugging.htm#tracer-1). E.g. if your functions are called `foo` and `bar` and you want to see calls to `excl::%puthash` from within those functions, you'd say:

```
(trace (excl::%puthash :inside (foo bar))
```

and if you want to see what the context of the call is, include a bit of the stack:

```
cl-user(1): (trace (excl::%puthash :inside foo :show-stack 3))
(excl::%puthash)
cl-user(2): (setf (gethash 3 (make-hash-table)) 2)
;; Note: no trace output, because not in foo
2
cl-user(3): (foo 3 (make-hash-table))
;; Note: within foo, so trace output which includes 3 stack frames
 0[2]: (excl::%puthash 3 #<eql hash-table with 0 entries @ #x100192cfa72> t)
 0^      <- (system::..runtime-operation "fwrap_start" 3 #<eql hash-table with 0 entries @ #x100192cfa72> t)
 0^      <- (foo 3 #<eql hash-table with 0 entries @ #x100192cfa72>)
 0^      <- (eval (foo 3 (make-hash-table)))
 0[2]: returned t
t
```

Tracing like this can be extremely helpful when dealing with unknown code.

The second thing to do, is checking the code to make sure that keys stored in the hash-table are not modified. E.g.

```
(let ((x (list 1 2))
      (ht (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
   (setf (gethash x ht) t)
   (setf (car x) 10) ;; not allowed!
   (gethash x ht)) ;; now in a funny state: may return T, or nil
```

See [18.1.2 Modifying Hash Table Keys](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/18_ab.htm).
Moreover [literal objects](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ga.htm) may not be modified either, that could be a cause of weirdness too:

```
(let ((x '(1 2)))
   (setf (car x) 10) ;; not allowed!
```